# Locally bind functions within lambda's

Tags: python, function, lambda, sum

Is there a way to locally bind functions within lambdas? I have a loop, and within each loop, I create an array of functions. I want to create another function which is the sum of all of these functions and store it in another array. This new array should hold the sum of all functions for each loop.
Then I want to create another function that is the sum over all the sum of functions.

However, the problem I have is that the original functions keep updating, so I am not getting my desired result. Can I locally bind the functions? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

```py
import numpy as np

lmax = 4
lapprox = []

# Function to estimate
def curve_func(x):
    return np.sin(x*np.pi)*x**2

# Initialise residual function
def residual_func(x):
    return curve_func(x)

# For each l, create 2**l+1 nodes and determine new nodes.
for l in range(lmax):  
    nodes = np.linspace(0, 1, 2**l+1, endpoint = True)
    if (l==0):
        old_nodes = nodes
        new_nodes = nodes
    else:
        old_nodes = np.linspace(0, 1, 2**(l-1)+1, endpoint = True)
        new_nodes = [x for x in nodes if x not in old_nodes]

    # Create basis function corresponding to each new node
    if (l==0):
        phi = [lambda x, i=i: max(1 - abs(2**l * x - i), 0) for i in range(len(new_nodes))]
    else:
        phi = [lambda x, i=i: max(1 - abs(2**l * x - (2*i+1)), 0) for i in range(len(new_nodes))]

    # Calculate hierarchical surpluses
    coeff = [residual_func(n) for n in new_nodes]

    # Array of functions: coeff*phi
    coeff_phi = [lambda x, func=func, alpha=alpha: coeff[alpha]*func(x) for alpha, func in enumerate(phi)]

    # Array of length lmax, where each value is sum of functions in coeff_phi for fixed l       
    lapprox.append(lambda x: sum(f(x) for f in coeff_phi)) 

    # Sum of all functions in lapprox           
    totapprox = lambda x: sum(f(x) for f in lapprox)

    # Compute new residual function
    residual_func = lambda x: curve_func(x) - totapprox(x)
```

Extra detail on what the code is doing: The code is designed to approximate a function, such as sin(pi*x)*x^2 using hierarchical linear splines. For each level `l`, there are some basis functions, given by the array `phi`. The function is approximated using a linear combination of some coefficients multiplied by these basis functions. The approximation is done sequentially, starting from a low-level, with few basis functions, until a high-level, with many basis functions. I need to keep track of the rolling approximation of the function to determine the values of the new coefficients.

Edit 2: I've defined the functions outside the loop. However, I am struggling in working out how to create a function to keep track of the residual_function. I have attached the 'dirty' solution that works as intended for `lmax=3`, but I would like to generalise it for any `lmax`. How can I do that?

```
def curve_func(x):
    return np.sin(x*np.pi)*x**2

def residual_func_0(x):
    return curve_func(x)

# Define nodes function
def make_nodes(l):
    return np.linspace(0, 1, 2**l+1, endpoint = True)
 
# Define new_nodes function
def make_new_nodes(l):
    if (l==0):
        new_nodes = np.linspace(0, 1, 2**l+1, endpoint = True)
    else:
        old_nodes = np.linspace(0, 1, 2**(l-1)+1, endpoint = True)
        new_nodes = [x for x in make_nodes(l) if x not in old_nodes]
    return new_nodes
    
# Define basis functions
def make_basis(l, i):
    if l == 0:
        return lambda x: max(1 - abs(2**l * x - i), 0)
    else:
        return lambda x: max(1 - abs(2**l * x - (2*i+1)), 0)

# Define coeff*basis functions
def make_scaled_basis(alpha, fn):
    return lambda x: alpha * fn(x)

new_nodes_0 = make_new_nodes(0)
new_nodes_1 = make_new_nodes(1)
new_nodes_2 = make_new_nodes(2)
new_nodes_3 = make_new_nodes(3)

phi_0 = [make_basis(0, i) for i in range(len(new_nodes_0))]
phi_1 = [make_basis(1, i) for i in range(len(new_nodes_1))]
phi_2 = [make_basis(2, i) for i in range(len(new_nodes_2))]
phi_3 = [make_basis(3, i) for i in range(len(new_nodes_3))]

coeff_0 = [curve_func(n) for n in new_nodes_0]
coeff_phi_0 = [make_scaled_basis(alpha, fn) for alpha, fn in zip(coeff_0, phi_0)]
residual_func_0 = lambda x: curve_func(x) - sum(f(x) for f in coeff_phi_0)

coeff_1 = [residual_func_0(n) for n in new_nodes_1]
coeff_phi_1 = [make_scaled_basis(alpha, fn) for alpha, fn in zip(coeff_1, phi_1)]
residual_func_1 = lambda x: residual_func_0(x) - sum(f(x) for f in coeff_phi_1)

coeff_2 = [residual_func_1(n) for n in new_nodes_2]
coeff_phi_2 = [make_scaled_basis(alpha, fn) for alpha, fn in zip(coeff_2, phi_2)]
residual_func_2 = lambda x: residual_func_1(x) - sum(f(x) for f in coeff_phi_2)

coeff_3 = [residual_func_2(n) for n in new_nodes_3]
coeff_phi_3 = [make_scaled_basis(alpha, fn) for alpha, fn in zip(coeff_3, phi_3)]
residual_func_3 = lambda x: residual_func_2(x) - sum(f(x) for f in coeff_phi_3)
```

Comment: You should provide more details on what this code is doing and why you need these lambda functions in the first place. Also perhaps you should create a custom class for this purpose.

Comment: Loops don't create a scope. You need to put what you want into a higher-order function so you'll get a scope, and call the function in the loop.

Comment: I added some more details on what the code is trying to do.

Comment: A lambda is no different than a `def` statement in this respect: any name in the body that is not a local variable (including parameters) is a free variable whose value is determined when the function is *called*. If you want a fixed value in the body of the variable, you need to create a new scope so that the free variable refers to a variable in a scope that hasn't changed since the function was defined.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to localize both `l` and `i` in the body of a function is to create a function that *returns* a function which closes over the local variables `l` and `i`.

For example:

```
def make_basis(l, i):
    if l == 0:
        return lambda x: max(1 - abs(2**l * x - i), 0)
    else:
        return lambda x: max(1 - abs(2**l * x - (2*i+1)), 0)

...

for l in range(lmax):
    ...

    phi = [make_basis(l, i) for i in range(len(new_nodes))]
```

Loops do not create new scopes; only function bodies do.

Comment: Thanks, I will try converting everything into functions. I was hoping there was something like `lambda x, i=i:` for localising functions.

Comment: That's kind of a special case, where the local variable `i` is initialized with the global (or at least non-local `i` in the current scope) when the function is defined, rather than when it is called. (In fact, both closures and default argument values are implemented similarly, being stored in the definition of the function itself.)

Comment: I updated my original comment - I've defined everything as function bodies now. However, I'm still struggling to work out how to define a function as described in my post. Do I need to use tailrecursion?